# JavaScript+CSS - Modifying cssText for 2d animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I did an exhaustive search trying to find a topic that solves my question, hope this is not a duplicate. Sorry if my English is confusing, I'm not native.

I'm trying to pass values from two predefined variables to my translate(x,y) values with CSS and JavaScript. I tried the following and some variations to it:

`CSS`

```
*
@keyframes bounce {
0% {
transform: translate(0em, 0em);
}
100% {
transform: translate(10em, 10em);
}
}
```

`Javascript`

```
var x = 5em;
var y = 5em;
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var ruleBounce = stylesheet.cssRules[0];
var ruleBounce_To = ruleBounce.cssRules[1];
ruleBounce_To_Style = ruleBounce_To.style;
ruleBounce_To_Style.cssText = 'transform: translate('+x+'em, '+y+'em)';
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. It just empties the cssText field. I've also tried putting the cssText into a variable and then changing it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a typo `var x = 5em;` it should be `5` since you're adding `em` later.
2. [CSSRule.cssText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule/cssText):

   > cssText returns the actual text of a [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) style-rule.
   >
   > Note: Can no longer be set directly, as [now specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#changes-from-5-december-2013) to be
   >   *functionally* modify-only -- and **silently** so -- meaning that
   >   attempting to set it does absolutely **nothing** -- not even warn or
   >   error.  Further, it has no settable sub-properties.  Therefore, to
   >   modify, use the stylesheet's cssRules[index] properties .selectorText
   >   and .style (or its sub-properties).  See [Using dynamic styling
   >   information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information) for details.

```js
var x = 5; // not 5em
var y = 5; // not 5em
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var ruleBounce = stylesheet.cssRules[0];
var ruleBounce_To = ruleBounce.cssRules[1];
ruleBounce_To_Style = ruleBounce_To.style;

console.log(ruleBounce_To_Style.cssText);

ruleBounce_To_Style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'em, ' + y + 'em)'; // see what you put here

console.log(ruleBounce_To_Style.cssText);
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0em, 0em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(10em, 10em);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! We just got to the same resolution with a colleague!

Comment: Happy to help !